# Echarts set different border radius for each value

Tags: javascript, echarts

### TLDR

In the graph below, some bars appear flipped, is there a way for all the bars to appear "normal"?

### Intro

I'm working on an echarts bar chart that can have multiple series and multiple y values. The value of each bar can be positive or negative, is there a way to change the border radius, depending on each value?

### What I tried

If there are no positive values (ignoring `0`), then I just use `[0, 0, 10, 10]` instead of  `[10, 10, 0, 0]` for the `barBorderRadius` property. But this is only guaranteed to work if there is only 1 y value.

In the example below the red b bar appears "upside down", but the green b appears as it should, since green a has no value.

### Minimal Example

```js
var dom = document.querySelector("#chart");

var data = {
  "red": {
    A: 400,
    B: -200
  },
  "green": {
    A: 0,
    B: -100
  },
  "blue": {
    A: 200,
    B: 0
  }
};
var colors = Object.keys(data);
var types = Object.keys(data[colors[0]]);

var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
myChart.setOption({
  color: colors,
  xAxis: [{
    type: "category",
    data: types
  }],
  yAxis: [{
    type: "value"
  }],
  series: colors.map(function(key) {
    var dataSet = Object.values(data[key]);
    var hasPositive = dataSet.filter(Boolean).some(function(val) {
      return val > 0;
    });
    return {
      name: key,
      type: "bar",
      itemStyle: {
        normal: {
          barBorderRadius: hasPositive ? [10, 10, 0, 0] : [0, 0, 10, 10]
        }
      },
      data: dataSet
    };
  })
});
```

```css
#chart {
  margin-top: -50px;
  height: 280px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://lib.baomitu.com/echarts/4.5.0/echarts-en.common.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find another answer so I'm just going to post my "hack" for anyone else that has no other way to fix a similar issue.

I've separated the data into multiple overlapping series of bars, the problem is that the set of bars on the left are shifted towards the left edge and the one on the right is shifted towards the right edge.

```js
var dom = document.querySelector("#chart");

var data = {
  "red": {
    A: 400,
    B: -200
  },
  "green": {
    A: 0,
    B: -100
  },
  "blue": {
    A: 200,
    B: 0
  }
};
var colors = Object.keys(data);
var types = Object.keys(data[colors[0]]);

var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
myChart.setOption({
  color: colors,
  xAxis: [{
    type: "category",
    data: types
  }],
  yAxis: [{
    type: "value"
  }],
  series: colors.reduce(function(result, color) {

    types.forEach(function(type, index) {
      var value = data[color][type];
      var dataList = "0".repeat(index).split("").map(function() {
        return NaN;
      });
      dataList[index] = value;

      result.push({
        name: color,
        type: "bar",
        barWidth: "25%",
        barGap: "-50%",
        itemStyle: {
          normal: {
            borderColor: color,
            borderWidth: 1,
            barBorderRadius: value < 0 ? [0, 0, 10, 10] : [10, 10, 0, 0]
          }
        },
        data: dataList
      });
    });

    return result;
  }, [])
});
```

```css
#chart {
  margin-top: -50px;
  height: 280px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://lib.baomitu.com/echarts/4.5.0/echarts-en.common.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

You can somewhat center the bars by adding more sets surrounding the real sets. You can add as many as you want, but you will have to adjust the width and the gap.

```js
var dom = document.querySelector("#chart");

var data = {
  "red": {
    A: 400,
    B: -200
  },
  "green": {
    A: 0,
    B: -100
  },
  "blue": {
    A: 200,
    B: 0
  }
};
var colors = Object.keys(data);
var types = Object.keys(data[colors[0]]);

var myChart = echarts.init(dom);
myChart.setOption({
  color: colors,
  xAxis: [{
    type: "category",
    data: types
  }],
  yAxis: [{
    type: "value"
  }],
  series: colors.reduce(function(result, color) {
    // left padding
    result.push({
      name: color,
      type: "bar",
      barWidth: "25%",
      barGap: "-75%",
      z: 0,
      data: [NaN, NaN]
    });

    types.forEach(function(type, index) {
      var value = data[color][type];
      var dataList = "0".repeat(index).split("").map(function() {
        return NaN;
      });
      dataList[index] = value;
      result.push({
        name: color,
        type: "bar",
        barWidth: "25%",
        barGap: "-75%",
        z: 10,
        itemStyle: {
          normal: {
            borderColor: color,
            borderWidth: 1,
            barBorderRadius: value < 0 ? [0, 0, 10, 10] : [10, 10, 0, 0]
          }
        },
        data: dataList
      });
    });

    // right padding
    result.push({
      name: color,
      type: "bar",
      barWidth: "25%",
      barGap: "-75%",
      z: 0,
      data: [NaN, NaN]
    });
    return result;
  }, [])
});
```

```css
#chart {
  margin-top: -50px;
  height: 280px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://lib.baomitu.com/echarts/4.5.0/echarts-en.common.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```